# Repeat ImageView in layout - Android

Tags: android

I want to repeat image in a layout. Number of times the image should be repeated , will be given dynamically. Image should be displayed Horizontally. How can I do this?

Please help me. Looking for your reply. Thanks.

Comment: Go with [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gallery.html)

Comment: Actually I want to display images horizontally as displayed in  RatingBar. How can I do this? Please tell me.

Comment: check this example: [Horizontal Scrolling Pages of Images in Android](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2012/05/14/horizontal-scrolling-pages/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this example. It'll helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

Not most efficient ways:

either you can create a single instance of you bitmap and set this in multiple imageviews created at runtime in a linear layout added in XMl.

or Override a view and draw the image using canvas multiple time at runtime.

Comment: Yes Dheeraj, You are right. I want the same as you are saying.

Comment: I think, 1st option is matching to my requirement

Comment: that is simple one, in that you need to create a Linear layout in XMl and get that by Id in java and add multiple image view with same image in a loop running as per count provided by you. Please let me know if there is any problem in this implementation as per your.requiment.

Comment: Hey yeah. I'll surely tell you. Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome.. Please let me know I 'll provide the code for same if needed, but I knew you can write that by yourself.......

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11230/discussion-between-krishna-suthar-and-dheeresh-singh)

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this

http://androidblogger.blogspot.in/2009/01/how-to-have-tiled-background-cont.html

Comment: Hi Ankita, I don't want to repeat background image. I want to repeat ImageView. Please give me some idea.

Comment: Can you give me some more hint ? why you need to repeat image in layout or what is the limit to repeation.

Comment: I want to create some design like it is in RatingBar. One image should be repeated horizontally for number of times given

Comment: you need only images, no need to handle click of them. right ?